# What is the ResiliencyGuid in CREATE_ / OPEN_VIRTUAL_DISK_PARAMETERS

Tags: winapi, vhd

I couldn't find any information on the `ResiliencyGuid` fields in the [`OPEN_VIRTUAL_DISK_PARAMETERS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323682(v=vs.85).aspx)/[`CREATE_VIRTUAL_DISK_PARAMETERS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323661(v=vs.85).aspx) structures of the Windows VHD API (when using version 2 of those structures).

- What is this Guid used for?
- How is it obtained?

Comment: Does your virtdisk.h have any clues? I only seem to have version 1 on me (despite getting the header files from what I hope was VS2013 Express for Windows Desktop...) (and MinGW-w64 also only has v1)

Comment: The version 2 structures are defined in Windows Kit 8.0 and 8.1; unfortunately there is no info beyond the definition in virtdisk.h :(

Comment: By info do you mean comments or actual GUIDs; if the former, are there GUIDs?

Comment: @andlabs There is neither.